# Cayley graphs for finitely presented Lie algebras

Tags: lie-algebras

I have seen that an important tool of finitely presented groups consists in writing down its Cayley graph with respect to a given set of generators, and then try to extract data like the coarse geometry or other things...

Does there exist a related theory for finitely generated Lie algebra?  I guess one of the first difficulties here is that a word [a,[b,c]] would decompose into a linear combination of words...

Thank you for any answer.

Klaus

Comment: Cayley graphs are defined in the same way for finitely generated groups, the data is just one group and one finite generating family. No presentation is involved.

Comment: I am confused.  Are you claiming that there are Cayley graphs for finitely generated Lie algebras?

I also don't understand why you say that the presentation is not interesting for the Cayley graph of a group?

As far as I understand the Cayley graph of a group has as vertices the elements of the group.  Then you connect to vertices $g$ and $h$ if $g = sh$ for some $s$ in the generating set $S$.  But I guess that to decide whether "$g=sh$" you do need to use the relations.

I don't work in algebra, so I'm sorry if I'm just mixing up things...

Comment: No. I said that Cayley graphs for groups are defined regardless of any presentation. I did't say anything about Lie algebras. But if there's an analogy, it should be with finitely generated Lie algebras.